Can you recommend a good book written on the history of Geometry?
Could you recommend a good book written on the history of Geometry? It would be even better if it were a comprehensive book covering from ancient Greek geometry to modern geometry.

Classic Coolidge, History of Geometrical Methods; recent, panoramic Scriba, 5000 Years of Geometry; modern period, scholarly Gray, Worlds Out of Nothing; turning points, biographic O'Leary, Revolutions of Geometry. It would help to describe what sort of history you are looking for, how much technical detail, cultural aspects, etc.

Personally I like Thomas Heath's style, his A History of Greek Mathematics has plenty of material about geometry https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=drnY3Vjix3kC&lpg=PR1&hl=tr&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q&f=false

I suggest 5000 Years of Geometry: Mathematics in History and Culture, by Christoph J. Scriba and Peter Schreiber.
